# How to alias a function to a symbol in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

It's not clear from the documentation how one might easily define a function, based on existing SymPy functions, and alias it to a particular symbol for printing.

For example, I have defined the rectangular function as follows.

```
import sympy as sp

def rect(t):
    return (sp.Heaviside(t + 1/2) - sp.Heaviside(t - 1/2))
```

While this is useful for the algebra side of things, preventing me from having to define a new Function subclass with derivatives and so forth, it would be nice if I could associate it with uppercase Pi (Π) so that expressions using it would print that instead of a series of Heaviside symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rect` would have to be a `class rect(Function)` instead of a function and it would need a custom printer. Note, too, that if you define the `eval` method as above (in terms of Heaviside) then your expression will no longer be the `rect` class...it will be an Add.

Another way to handle this would be to just use `Function('\Pi')(t)` in your expressions and when you are ready to do something with them, replace those instances with your definition.  But what sorts of things do you want to do with the `rect`? Could you use a Piecewise instead?